# jqgrid inlinenav save/edit not available with hidden id column

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I have a jqgrid with an id that is a db sequence and thus the user doesn't need to see it.  When the column is marked as 'hidden : true' the inlinenav edit is not clickable and the save won't save.  It works fine when I comment that out.

```
$("#grid_d").jqGrid(
{
url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/testjson?id=0",
datatype : "json",
colNames : [ "id", "analyte","units" ],
colModel : [ {
    name: 'id',
    index: 'id',
    hidden : true,
    editable : true
}, {
    name : 'analyte',
    index : 'analyte',
    editable : true
}, {
    name : 'unit',
    index : 'unit',
    editable : true
} ],
sortname : 'id',
pager : '#pager_d',
viewrecords : true,
editurl : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editjson"
});
$("#grid_d").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager_d", {
    edit : false,
    add : false,
    del : true
}, {}, // edit options.
{}, // add options.
{
    reloadAfterSubmit : false,
    afterSubmit : deleteMessage,
    msg: "Delete selected analyte(s)"
}, // del options.
{}, // search options.
{} // view options. 
);
$("#grid_d").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager_d");
```

Comment: Please post your jqGrid definition code.

Comment: Added code to original post